# Error: int cannot be converted to String, when I use: timer = new Timer(1000, this);

Tags: java

I made a timer which I declared by timer = new Timer(1000, this); (see below for full code). But I get the error: Error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String. Does this mean that the compiler thinks that "this" is a string or..? What should I do to fix this error?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Snake extends JFrame implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
/*Painter painter;
LinkedList<Point> snakeList;*/
Timer timer;
/*int direction;
int snakeSize;
int movementX, movementY;*/

public static void main(String[] arg){
    new Snake();
}

public Snake(){
    /*painter = new Painter(this);
    this.add(painter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.requestFocusInWindow();*/
    timer = new Timer(1000, this);
    /*startGame();*/
}

/*public void startGame(){
    snakeList = new LinkedList<Point>();
    snakeList.addFirst(new Point(30,30));
    snakeSegments(3);
    movementX = 0;
    movementY = 0;
}

public void gameUpdate(){
    snakeMove(movementX, movementY);
    repaint();
}

public void snakeSegments(int i){
    snakeSize = getSnakeSize();
    while(snakeSize > 0){
        snakeList.addLast(new Point(getLast()));
        snakeSize--;
    } 
}

public void snakeInstructor(){
    int currentDirection = getDirection();
    if (currentDirection == 1){
        snakeMove(-1, 0);
    } else if (currentDirection == 2){
        snakeMove(1, 0);
    } else if (currentDirection == 3){
        snakeMove(0, 1);
    } else if (currentDirection == 4){
        snakeMove(0, -1);
    }      
}

public void snakeMove(int directionX, int directionY){
    snakeList.getFirst().x = snakeList.getFirst().x + directionX;
    snakeList.getFirst().y = snakeList.getFirst().y + directionY;
    for(int i = getSnakeSize()-1; i >=1; i--) {
        snakeList.get(i).setLocation(snakeList.get(i-1));
    }
}

public void setDirection(int newDirection){
    direction = newDirection;
}

public int getDirection (){
    return direction;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return true;
}

Point getFirst(){
    return snakeList.getFirst();
}

Point getLast(){
    return snakeList.getLast();
}

Point get(int i){
    return snakeList.get(i);
}

public void addFirst(Point p){
    snakeList.addFirst(p);
}

public void addLast(Point p){
    snakeList.addLast(p);
}

public Point removeFirst(){
    snakeList.removeFirst();
    return null;
}

public Point removeLast(){
    snakeList.removeLast();
    return null;
}

public int getSnakeSize(){
    return snakeList.size();
}

public void setSnakeSize(){
    snakeSize = snakeList.size() + 1;
}*/

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    gameUpdate();
}

/*@Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){ }
@Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){ }
@Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && direction != 2){
        setDirection(1);
    } else if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && direction != 1){
        setDirection(2);
    } else if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) && direction != 4){
        setDirection(3);
    } else if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) && direction != 3){
        setDirection(4);
    } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        startGame();
    }
}*/

}
```

Comment: You've imported java.util.Timer but you seem to be wanting to use a javax.swing.Timer

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know there was a difference. Thanks! By the way, if you put your comment as an answer I can select it as the answer because now I can't.

Comment: This is why namespaces (`java.util`, `javax.swing`, etc) exist in languages like Java. Because, as more and more libraries and APIs are released, there's an increased chance of two (different and probably unrelated) classes having to share the same name. Namespaces are a way to distinguish between your `Timer` class and my `Timer` class, your `Window` class and my `Window` class, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've imported `java.util.Timer` but you seem to be wanting to use a `javax.swing.Timer`